# Strip <p> tag from within <script> tags

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

content:

```
Various html here
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<p>
valid.js.here
</p>    <p>
more.valid.js.here
</p>
</script>
more htmls here
```

Ive tried

```
preg_replace('#<script[^>]*>(<p>|</p>)</script>#is', '', $content);
```

and other variations on that.  Basically, this is wordpress's wonderful wpautop. No, I cant turn off autop in the various other ways.

Answer (score 0):

Even if that would match, you would replace the whole script block with ''.

I recommend reading up on REGEX in general and `preg_replace` 
(maybe even `preg_replace_callback`).

Also it might be a good idea to first extract the scripts content and in an second step to remove the tags.

Further this will not work if you do have `<p>` in your JS code which you want to keep. (like in js strings)

Here is a quite useful regex testing app I use: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: Extracting the scripts content, then str_replace() the <p> would work fine (in this case; I see your point about needed <p>)

Answer (score 0):

$content ="abc.js ";
$output=preg_replace('/

\s*(<script.*>*.</script>)\s*</p>/iU', '\1', $content);

Comment: You seem to be trying to answer, thanks. Find helpful info on writing answers which are perceived as helpful here: [answer] and https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help